# Would TFA be a strong enough acid to perform an SN1 reaction on alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

The pKa of sulfuric acid, which is usually used to do this reaction is -3, but would TFA be sufficient even though it has a pKa of 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. TFA is widely used for alcohol dehydration, for example as described in this [review](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/NP/2020/D0NP00009D).

TFA is a standard reagent for the ionic hydrogenation of alcohols with hydrosilanes which proceeds via the protonation of the alcohol and the formation of the cation [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductions_with_hydrosilanes)